# Linq query through database with every word

Tags: c#, sql, linq

The best I can show you what I am trying to achieve is with an example.

Lets say that the user enters a search sentence like 'Microsoft Exchange Server'.
So my SQL query would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Skills
WHERE Line5 LIKE '%Microsoft%' AND Line5 LIKE '%Exchange%' AND Line5 LIKE '%Server%';
```

So it looks the following in Linq:

```
.Where(x => x.Line5.Contains("Microsoft") && x.Line5.Contains("Exchange")&& x.Line5.Contains("Server")).ToList();
```

The problem is that I don't know how many words the user enters into the query. So how would I perform that query with x amount of words. The query has to be an AND search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Where` you may use `All` against a dynamic user word list:

```
var userWords = new[] { "Microsoft", "Exchange", "Server" };
var selected = tbl_Skills.Where(x => userWords.All(w => x.Line5.Contains(w)));
```